# Play .wav files on Android phone

Tags: android, playback, wav

I need to complete an app on an Android phone that plays back four sound files when four separate buttons are pressed.

The trouble I have is that the sound files are .wav files. They are also stereo files. I need to play them on the Android phone uncompressed and in stereo.

My understanding is that .wav can not be played on Android phones as it is uncompressed and that I will need to convert the file format but I have not had any luck that way.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Android certainly can open/play WAV files.

Use `android.media.MediaPlayer` to play them, as you'd do for mp3 or other format.

Comment: That app does not play WAV files on my Motorola Photon 4G.

Comment: I just now tried the Remote Wave Android app and found it was able to play WAV files correctly on the Motorola Photon 4G.

Answer (score 1):

See the following list for a complete reference of supported media formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Wave is supported, PCM/WAVE 8- and 16-bit linear PCM (rates up to limit of hardware) WAVE (.wav)

Answer (score 0):

From Android 4.0.1 Android supports Wave (.wav) formats, you can access 8bit or 16 bit audio files in .wav format